# Using JPA cursor takes more time during data pulling and at the end OutOfMemory exception occured

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, cursor

Suppose I have a database (Postgres) with 12 million row. then I want to get data with  a page size 30k using jpa cursor. but during the first request it consume significantly more time.
here is my query hints:

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.CURSOR, true)
             .setHint(QueryHints.SCROLLABLE_CURSOR, true)
             .setHint("eclipselink.read-only", "true")
             .setHint(QueryHints.CURSOR_INITIAL_SIZE, 30000)
             .setHint(QueryHints.CURSOR_PAGE_SIZE, 30000);
```

now when calling using

```
cursor = (CursoredStream) query.getSingleResult();
list = cursor.next(Math.min((rangeCount - o), pageSize));
```

it consumes almost 236 sec for executing first line (executing the query).

my `persistent.xml` configuration for cursor given below,

```
<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
  <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="off" />
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

can anyone help me, how to reduce the time and overcome from `OutOfMemory` exception?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your query like?

Comment: select o.id, o.appBiometric.fingerprintId from  AppData o 
                 where o.lockApp=0 and o.application.applicationState not in (30, 32, 31, 42, 27)
                AND o.creationDate <= '2015-08-29 08:26:37.385' and o.id >= 0 order by  o.id asc

Comment: And does that result in a reasonable SQL query? You might want to check the Postgres side performance first.

Comment: Postgres side performance is ok, my thought was during the first req it pulled all the row in the database then cursor it. @Kayaman

Comment: Well it will build the resultset before it will give a cursor to it, but that will happen at the DB side. I would try smaller initial and page sizes first to see how that'll affect performance.

Comment: adding smaller initial like 1k and page size 1k, it takes 165 sec for first req, but java usages memory over 2GB.

Comment: The Postgres driver buffers the whole ResultSet in memory unless you tell it not do so so: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html#query-with-cursor

Answer (score 1):

According to the [postgres JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html), the following criteria must be met for the `ScrollableCursor` to work, otherwise it would just read the whole result into the `ResultSet`:

- The connection to the server must be using the V3 protocol. This is the default for (and is only supported by) server versions 7.4 and later.
- The Connection must not be in autocommit mode. The backend closes cursors at the end of transactions, so in autocommit mode the backend will have closed the cursor before anything can be fetched from it.
- The Statement must be created with a ResultSet type of ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. This is the default, so no code will need to be rewritten to take advantage of this, but it also means that you cannot scroll backwards or otherwise jump around in the ResultSet.
- The query given must be a single statement, not multiple statements strung together with semicolons.

So make sure you add the following Hints to your code:

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, 500);
query.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_SET_TYPE, ResultSetType.ForwardOnly);
```

Sometimes when using EclipseLink as JPA *autocommit* gets set to true, so unwrapping the connection with the `EntityManager` sets it back to false:

```
em.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you get the `OutOfMemory` exception when executing the first query ? If the answer is **no**, maybe the problem is that you forgot to `close()` your cursor after each query to free its resources.

Java always have been and always will use a lot of memory. However, in my opinion, since this is server-side code, this should be executed in a remote machine with 4GB or more RAM, not in a regular computer. Especially when dealing with millions of rows.

Comment: OutOfMemory Exception overcome by clearing cursor but still it takes almost 170 sec for first pulling.